# How to Accelerate Java Web Testing

Tags: java

I am coding an intricate method in a Spring Controller that takes as input request.getParameterMap().  In developing the method iteratively, each time I make a tweak, I have to Deploy, and then go through the steps on the web form.

That process can take minutes, just to tweak a small code change.

Are there any tricks or methods to speed up this process?  All I really need is the input from request.getParameterMap().  Can I serialize that Map data somehow, and re-use it?

I am using Netbeans, if that is relevant.

Comment: Why don't you use unit testing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience the best is to setup a JUnit test, which doesn't use the web server at all, but just instantiates the controller, calls the method and checks the result.

Since your controller wasn't written from the ground up for this kind of approach, it might be quite some work to get this going at this stage. If you post the method in question we might help with this.

The next best thing is setting up an integration test, which starts up the application server, executes the request (possibly through the actual web gui using selenium or something).

Still a lot of work, but the difficulties are less dependent on the current workstyle.

As a final work around you can try to make the roundtrip for a manual test faster. There might be IDE dependent possibilities so you would have to let us know about the IDE in use.

I haven't tested it, but many people praise JRebel for this kind of thing, so you might want to give it a try.

Comment: I will take your advice the next go-round.  I am a bit too far into this now, though.  I ended up serializing and deserializing the requestParameterMap which seems to be working.  But it sounds like Junit is the right approach next time.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to fill the web form again and again try Jmeter(It's a free load testing tool).
Create a test plan with -> set number of threads to 1 --> http request sampler -> set method to post and add post parameters. Once everthing is setup fire the request

please check this link below for reference
http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65142-the-new-http-sampler-in-jmeter-2-6